# Error cannot declare instance members in a static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
```

I am receiving this error

```
cannot declare instance members in a static class
```

when writing a Static class.
Any idea how to solve it keeping the class static if possible? Thanks

```
namespace XXX.Helpers
{
    public static class Utility
    {
        public static string GetConfiguration(string section, string key)
        {
            NameValueCollection mySection = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(section);

            return mySection[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the instance members?

Comment: i tried using your code but it didn't gave me any error..

Comment: Duplicate: [**cannot declare instance members in a static class in C#**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063481/cannot-declare-instance-members-in-a-static-class-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't see any error in provide code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not define non-static members in a `static` class. It is not legal to declare an instance member in a static class.

From [`Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

> The following list provides the main features of a static class:
>
> - **Contains only static members.**
> - Cannot be instantiated.
> - Is sealed.
> - Cannot contain Instance Constructors.

I have to say, I don't see any instance member in your static class by the way `:)`

Answer (score 1):

> cannot declare instance members in a static class

The reason for this error is because -

**Static class should only contains static members**

Comment: The class doesn't have any members though. Just a static function. Static functions in return CAN have non-static members.

Comment: @Eisenhorn ah..you are right, I just jumped to answer with out cheking the code.