# c# Concatenate static arrays inside static class

Tags: c#, arrays, constructor, static, concatenation

I am not even sure how to call what I want to achieve but... probably the code will explain it.

Basically, I would like to create the frames commands as combinations of some statically defined arrays.

I would like to do something like this:

> Command = ConcatArrays(commandPart1, commandPart2, commandPart2)

But it fails inside ConcatArrays as the list elements seem to be null.

And to use externally like this:

> Frame.Frame1.Command

The ConcatArrays I took it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063504/15872

Is it something like this possible?

Thanks a lot for any help, I am quite new to C#.

```
public static class Frame
{

public class RequestModel
{
    public byte[] Command { get; set; }
    public int ReceiveLength { get; set; }
}

public static RequestModel Frame1 = new RequestModel
{
    Command = ConcatArrays(commandPart1, commandPart2, commandPart2)
    ReceiveLength = 16,
};

public static RequestModel Frame2 = new RequestModel
{
    Command = ConcatArrays(commandPart1, commandPart3)
    ReceiveLength = 16,
};

private static byte[] commandPart1 = new byte[] { 0x1, 0x02 };
private static byte[] commandPart2 = new byte[] { 0x3, 0x4 };
private static byte[] commandPart3 = new byte[] { 0x5, 0x6 };

public static T[] ConcatArrays<T>(params T[][] list)
{
    var result = new T[list.Sum(a => a.Length)];
    int offset = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++)
    {
        list[x].CopyTo(result, offset);
        offset += list[x].Length;
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

Comment: What are frames commands?

Comment: @LukeHutton I was referring to Frame1 -> Command, Frame2 -> Command or is not what are you asking?

Comment: Oh I see, I thought perhaps this was a known design pattern perhaps. What is your question then? By possible, do you mean will your code run? We need the ability to verify your requirements

Comment: I would like to be able to write this: Command = ConcatArrays(commandPart1, commandPart2, commandPart2) but it fails @LukeHutton

Comment: The linked page context is not related to handling Arrays. `Command` is undefined. Your class as it is won't compile (not valid C# code). The only thing that I'm pretty sure is working is the `ConcatArrays()` method. A correct (assumed from code correspondance) link could be this answer [Can I use an array initializer to build one byte array out of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127394/c-sharp-can-i-use-an-array-initializer-to-build-one-byte-array-out-of-another/39127457#39127457)

Comment: @Jimi Sorry, I forgot to add the RequestModel. Updated the question which already has the solution now

Comment: It's good you have a solution. The commas in `RequestModel` are still in the wrong place, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to static members below. For example, `Frame1` member referencing `commandPart1` static member defined below it in the static class.

One way to fix is to define the static members above where referenced. The following tests pass:

```
    [Test]
    public void Frame1CommandShouldIncludeParts1and2and2()
    {
        var expected = new byte[] {0x1, 0x02, 0x3, 0x4, 0x3, 0x4};
        var actual = Frame.Frame1.Command;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Frame2CommandShouldIncludeParts1and3()
    {
        var expected = new byte[] {0x1, 0x02, 0x5, 0x6};
        var actual = Frame.Frame2.Command;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    public class RequestModel
    {
        public byte[] Command { get; set; }
        public int ReceiveLength { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Frame
    {
        private static readonly byte[] CommandPart1 = { 0x1, 0x02 };
        private static readonly byte[] CommandPart2 = { 0x3, 0x4 };
        private static readonly byte[] CommandPart3 = { 0x5, 0x6 };

        public static RequestModel Frame1 = new RequestModel
        {
            Command = ConcatArrays(CommandPart1, CommandPart2, CommandPart2),
            ReceiveLength = 16
        };
        public static RequestModel Frame2 = new RequestModel
        {
            Command = ConcatArrays(CommandPart1, CommandPart3),
            ReceiveLength = 16
        };

        private static T[] ConcatArrays<T>(params T[][] list)
        {
            var result = new T[list.Sum(a => a.Length)];
            int offset = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++)
            {
                list[x].CopyTo(result, offset);
                offset += list[x].Length;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `ConcatArrays()` method could just be `return list.SelectMany(a1 => a1.Select(a2 => a2)).ToArray();` (for the Lambda addicted :)

Comment: Thank you so much, Luke! I can't believe I wasted so much time for this :)) just because of position LOL